# Website running slow on clients machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net, windows

I have a web application which i am hosting. It is working fine on my machine and most machines i try on.

My client is saying the functionality of the web application is working fine. However, it takes ages for the site to load on his machine and if he presses a button the site takes ages to process things. He has also said he has tried the site on another machine and gotten the same issue.

How can i test what is the issue on the clients machine?

Comment: Please use appropriate tags. None of those you used are relevant to the question. Have you considered that performance you are seeing might be due to caching at your end? Clear all caches and test again. Then test from another location, preferably using a different ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, if there are more than one DNS entries in the network adapter TCP/IP properties and the first DNS is not responding, it will take time for the name resolution process to time-out and then use the fallback DNS which then works and you get a result after a long delay.  See if the client has the same problem in general when accessing the other sites and also note if the browser's status bar reads looking for website . . . for a long time before it changes to transferring . . .

Comment: Yeh it says waiting for site http://...

Comment: In my experience, that is a good indication that the primary DNS is not working.  Try setting up a a different DNS local on that machine in the TCP/IP settings for the network adpater properties. May be try 4.2.2.2 and see if the site starts responding quickly.  Assuming that the URL is NOT restricted to INTRANET within the organization.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can't access the client machine yourself (e.g. using VNC) and don't expect the client to install firebug/pagespeed/yslow, then you'll need to start looking at the packet stream from your end using e.g. wireshark or add bugs to the page which can analyse performance (e.g. Yahoo Boomerang). However these approaches will only show you information about the structure of the site / network behaviour - a slow response to key presses on the browser has nothing to do with sending stuff across the network - its exclusively about what's happenning on the client.

Do they see better performance with other websites? Which ones? Check what browser they are using (I had to reinstall FF3 after upgrading to FF4 due to the horrendous performance problems). It could be a misbehaving bit of code (e.g. malware or a tool like Rapport) on the client. Or do you have event handlers on the input fields?

Comment: is there something that will just let me know bytes received and sent

Comment: you should already know what your web pages look like. This information should already be in your logs. How does this help you find out how fast those bytes are going?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a third-party like [Gomez](http://www.gomez.com/instant-test-pro/).

Comment: Im pretty sure there is noting wrong with the website. I want to be able to look and test the clients network and see what is wrong